# graphite render view throws exception

Tags: python, django, graphite

When I try to get graphite render view, I get following stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "../webapp/graphite/render/views.py", line 113, in renderView
    seriesList = evaluateTarget(requestContext, target)
  File "../webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 10, in evaluateTarget
    result = evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens)
  File "../webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 21, in evaluateTokens
    return evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens.expression)
  File "../webapp/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 24, in evaluateTokens
    return fetchData(requestContext, tokens.pathExpression)
  File "../webapp/graphite/render/datalib.py", line 230, in fetchData
    dbResults = dbFile.fetch( timestamp(startTime), timestamp(endTime), timestamp(now))
TypeError: fetch() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

If I look at my datalib.py, I find following

```
...
...
228   for dbFile in store.find(pathExpr):
229     log.metric_access(dbFile.metric_path)
230     dbResults = dbFile.fetch( timestamp(startTime), timestamp(endTime), timestamp(now))
231     results = dbResults
232 
...
...
```

On line 230, dbFile.fetch has exactly 3 arguments. Why does my stack trace show (4 given)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; in my case the problem was that I installed graphite-web from the pip repository ( pip install graphite-web ); while I had carbon (collector engine) and whisper (storage engine) from the package manager on my Raspberry pi (raspbian).

Result: different versions of the components. After installing everything through pip (http://graphite.wikidot.com/downloads) graphs were showing.